# upcasting from derived to templated base in C++

Tags: c++, casting

EDIT:

I realized that this code compiles and works:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Something> class Base {
public:
    Base() {

    }

    virtual ~Base() {
    }

    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base<std::string> {
public:
    Derived() {

    }

    virtual ~Derived() {

    }

    void method() {
    }
};

template<class Something> class TemplatedClass {
public:
    void method(Base<Something>* base) {
    }
};

class SomeClass: public TemplatedClass<std::string> {
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Derived* d = new Derived();

    Base<std::string>* b = d;
    Base<std::string>* b1 = dynamic_cast<Base<std::string>*>(d);
    Base<std::string>* b2 = static_cast<Base<std::string>*>(d);

    SomeClass sc;
    sc.method(b);
    sc.method(b1);
    sc.method(b2);
}
```

Then, I am doing a really big mistake preparing the skeleton or even trying to understand my own code. WHAT a SHAME!!! Sorry... This is a really bad question. It would be better to remove it...

** NO SENSE QUESTION AND CODE BELOW **
Given this:

```
template<class Something> class Base
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base<std::string>
{
    void method() { ... };
};
```

I want to downcast a pointer of `Derived` to a pointer of `Base`. I tried to use `dynamic_cast` with no success:

```
...
Derived* d = new Derived();
Base* b = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d);
...
```

I always got errors during execution.

I don't know if I need downcasting,. I have this situation:

```
template<class Something> class TemplatedClass
{
    void method(Base<Something>* base) { ... };
};

class SomeClass : public TemplatedClass<std::string> { ... };
```

And I want to call (EDITED*):

```
Derived* d = new Derived();

SomeClass sc;
sc.method(d);
```

But it gives me an conversion error.

What does I need? Downcasting or what?

Comment: yes, it is upcasting! arrrgg...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your test actually looked like this?

```
Base<std::string>* b = dynamic_cast<Base<std::string> *>(d);
```

i.e. it has to be a cast to the instantiated template, not `Base` without a type argument.

Wait a second - you're doing derived to base!

```
Base<std::string>* b = d;
```

That should be fine!

Your second example doesn't look right - in particular:

```
SomeClass sc();
```

That should be:

```
SomeClass sc;
```

Can you post the real code and the exact error message?

Comment: I have edited it, it was a mistake, sorry. I cannot post real code, it have copyrigths form my company, sorry. I have prepared similar code, only with skeletons to explain my issues. The errors are 'invalid static_cast' when I try to do static_cast, 'no matching function for call to' and 'o known conversion for argument 1 form' when I tried to call function directly without casting and runtime errors when I tried dynamic_cast.

Comment: @logoff at least post code that either compiles or produces the exact same error you're having.

Comment: Is there a copyright problem preventing you from giving the compiler error? :)

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry, it has no sense at all. I posted compiling code and it has no errors and it works. Sorry.